# Can metacharacters be used in a regular expression as a normal character?

Tags: regex, metacharacters

I was wondering if metacharacters, such as ? or *, can be used in a regular expression as a normal character instead of metacharacters.

For example, I have the following text:

```
"Hi. How are you? What time is it? Beep?"
```

And I wanted to use regular expressions to substring each group of words ending with a question mark (?).

Therefore resulting in:

```
Hi.
How are you?
What time is it?
Beep?
```

Thanks

Comment: That's the whole purpose of having character class. You can define them like this `[?*.]` will allow either of three characters, which are **meta-characters** outside it.

Comment: No; that's the point of the backslash.

Comment: @SLaks: Yea backslash can also do that. I was talking in terms of collective declaration. Don't wanna use \.\?\*. It seems complicated.

Comment: @noob I do not want to use '?' as a metacharater. I want to be able to find the question marks in the text using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for `?` followed by an optional space and replace it with a `?` and `newline` like this.

**Regex:** `\?\s?` Here `?` is escaped.

[`[?]\s?` does the same.](https://regex101.com/r/yN5xX3/2)

**Replacement:** Replace with `?\n`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN5xX3/1)